Delphi Editor - what does blue arrow mean?

My debugging always stops at this line 1989 that has a blue right arrow.
I thought it should only stop at those with the red check (line 1987).
How can I add/remove the blue right arrow?

That icon just indicates the current line of execution. As you step through the program, that icon will move with the line of code being executed.
If the program breaks at a point near where the break point is, but not exactly there, then there are typically two causes in my experience.

Your source file contains some unexpected line end characters. The IDE is quite fussy about line ends being CR/LF. You can use a tool to fix this. Many text editors have the ability to resolve this.
The list of breakpoints has got out of sync with the IDE. Open the breakpoints window and delete them all. Then restart the IDE, set your breakpoint again, and all should be well.



The line 1987 contain conditional breakpoint whose condition was not met therefore debugger did not stop at it.



Maybe a full build (Shift + F9) is necessary to force the recreation of all dcu files


@DavidHeffernan you are right. the breakpoints were out of sync. I deleted all using View-Debug Windows-Breakpoints. Thank you!
